# want to find with two request values

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to update my column data with two request values. I tried it one value. and I have no idea about where and method.

```
Gold::where('type', '=', $request->type)->firstOrFail();
```

this is only for one request value query search. but I want to check two values pass in type and parent_id with where query.how can I do it with laravel find method. finally, I want to update check both values include data and update it's other column values like this.

```
$gold = Gold::where('type', '=', $request->type)->firstOrFail();
$gold->comment = $request->input('comment');
$gold->userid = $request->input('userid');
$gold->save();
```

Comment: Is the Gold type really a property in the ```$request``` object? Why don't you get it with ```$request->input('type')```? Also, what errors are shown?

Comment: @Augusto Moura Gold is my model name

Comment: What I mean is: does ```$request->type``` return anything? What errors are shown?

Comment: @Augusto Moura simply i want to update values with using 2 request values. i done 1 request value and i have no idea with 2 request values.

Comment: @Augusto Moura this is my mysql query i want to write it in laravel . 
select * from all_items where type='type' and parent_id='parent_id';  i want to update this search reasult data

Answer (score 0):

According to you SQL query which you provided in your question comment here is the solution with Laravel Model:-

```
# this query will find your Gold item with there provided where conditions.
# you can pass more where conditions as per your requirements.
$gold = Gold::where('type', '=', $request->input('type'))
            ->where('parent_id', '=', $request->input('parent_id'))->first();

if(!$gold) {
    return throw Exception('Invalid Gold Item', 422);
}

$gold->comment = $request->input('comment');
$gold->userid = $request->input('userid');
$gold->save();
```

Here is the solution as per your requirement which I understand.